# Адаптивные сайты. Телефон

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я написал адаптивную страничку. При помощи медиа-запросов.

```
@screen-xs-max: 769px;
@screen-sm-min: 770px;
@screen-sm-max: 1440px;
@screen-md-min: 1441px;
```

Выложил её на хостинг : http://holiday-friends.zzz.com.ua/ 
и просмотрев с телефона (hd разрешение) увидел что она под планшет.

1. Что я мог сделать не так?
2. Если телефон с разрешением fullhd, но там 5 дюймов экран, как тут быть ведь выставлено `@screen-xs-max: 769px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В head нужно добавить:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Comment: а это разве не азы?